# How to split the data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have data like this:

```
a = 1 ; c = 3; d= c;
```

I would like to get the data from SQL Server

```
1
3
c
```

How to do split between `=` and `;` ? Please help me. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(300)
DECLARE @combinedString VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @tmp TABLE(variable nvarchar(max), value nvarchar(max))

SET @S='a=1;c=3;d=c;'

;WITH MyRows AS
(

    SELECT LEFT(@s, CHARINDEX(';', @s) -1) AS MyRow, RIGHT(@s, LEN(@s) - CHARINDEX(';', @s)) AS Remainder
    UNION ALL
    SELECT LEFT(Remainder, CHARINDEX(';', Remainder) -1) AS MyRow, RIGHT(Remainder, LEN(Remainder) - CHARINDEX(';', Remainder)) AS Remainder
    FROM MyRows
    WHERE CHARINDEX(';', Remainder)>0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Remainder AS MyRow, NULL AS Remainder
    FROM MyRows
    WHERE CHARINDEX(';', Remainder)=0
)
INSERT INTO @tmp (variable, value)
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(max), SUBSTRING(MyRow, 1, 1)) AS variable, CONVERT(nvarchar(max),SUBSTRING(MyRow, 3, LEN(MyRow))) AS value
FROM MyRows

SELECT @combinedString = COALESCE(@combinedString + ' ', '') + value
FROM @tmp

SELECT @combinedString As Value
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank. Can you help me how to split for this below statment I have the data [-0.999,0.999]. I would like to field split assign val = -0.999 and val 1 = 0.999. How to do? pls help me

Comment: @NaingLay What you want to split?